# Servlet - Addressing properties files

Tags: java, servlets, properties

I have a simple Servlet that needs to pass some `properties` files to another class.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("/home/user/config.properties"));
```

Above works fine.

But I can't address the right absolute path in below:

```
String protocol = prop.getProperty("protocol", "/home/user/protocol.properties");
String routes = prop.getProperty("routes", "/home/user/routes.properties");
MyClass message = new MyClass(protocol, routes, 0);
```

At the end I receive below from `tomcat` log:

```
    INFO: Server startup in 3656 ms
java.io.FileNotFoundException: routes.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at com.cc.verticals.Messenger.<init>(Messenger.java:134)
    at com.foo.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:42)
    at com.verticals.cc.util.VerticalUtil.setup(VerticalUtil.java:59)
    at com.verticals.cc.util.VerticalUtil.main(VerticalUtil.java:259)
    at com.verticals.cc.dao.VerticalDao.<init>(VerticalDao.java:24)
    at com.verticals.cc.controller.VerticalController.<init>(VerticalController.java:33)
```

Line 42 is pointing to the constructor where `routes.properties` file goes in.

Messenger line 134 points to:

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream(routesFilename));
```

Any Idea how to address the properties files and send them as a `String` parameter? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the line of code that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it (I prefer if you post the content's of the properties files), there is a property within config.properties such that `routes = routes.properties`. When you call `new file(routes);` you get the `FileNotFoundException` because you are trying to open `routes.properties` in the current working directory where java was launched (which doesn't exist)

As a side note, you using one property file to reference another property, which is fine but a bit odd or unconventional. Further, you should stick these files in a 'resource' folder to remove absolute paths and gain portability.

Comment: the `routes.properties` just contains some `urls` e.g: `url=tcp://localhost:5556`. If I add the files in `resource` folder then I need to use `FileInputStream` but I need to get the file path as a `String`

Comment: @stsd what does `config.properties` have? does it have `routes = routes.properties`? Could you please post what is in those property files?

Comment: Yes, it does `routes = routes.properties`

Comment: That is why it is failing, change it to `/home/user/routes.properties`

Comment: Thanks, I placed them in `resource` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that prop.getProperty method cannot throw FileNotFoundException. So that exception must have been thrown earlier on prop.load();

Please make sure that you have opened the permissions on the file. Open a terminal and issue following command:

```
$ chmod 777 /home/user/routes.properties
$ chmod 777 /home/user/protocol.properties
```